# serverless failed to add package "pg" (postgres) in build

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless, typeorm, pg

I am working with lambda implementation using serverless and using TypeOrm + Postgres as a Database interaction layer, Everything work perfectly in the local environment.

Issue :
While I am deploying my lambda function using "serverless deploy", It will not add or ignoring dependency "pg". When I'm running lambda getting the following error. I using serverless.yml to configure.

> 2020-10-14T07:58:56.144Z 4faab731-d745-485c-8f2a-5e6de78331d7 ERROR
> DriverPackageNotInstalledError: Postgres package has not been found
> installed. Try to install it: npm install pg --save at new
> DriverPackageNotInstalledError
> (/var/task/node_modules/typeorm/error/DriverPackageNotInstalledError.js:10:28)
> at PostgresDriver.loadDependencies
> (/var/task/node_modules/typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresDriver.js:967:19)
> at new PostgresDriver
> (/var/task/node_modules/typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresDriver.js:203:14)
> at DriverFactory.create
> (/var/task/node_modules/typeorm/driver/DriverFactory.js:35:24) at new
> Connection
> (/var/task/node_modules/typeorm/connection/Connection.js:53:59) at
> ConnectionManager.create
> (/var/task/node_modules/typeorm/connection/ConnectionManager.js:56:26)
> at DatabaseGateway. (/var/task/DatabaseGateway.js:68:52) at
> Generator.next () at /var/task/DatabaseGateway.js:33:71 at
> new Promise ()

I have tried and checked :

- "pg" is available in package.json (not in dev dependency)
- tried by deleting dist and package-lock.json
- also added dependency (inside serverless.yml) forcefully using

> ```
> custom:
> webpackIncludeModules:
> forceInclude:
> - pg
> ```

Thanks.